# Write simple service in Angular

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular framework and I am going to create a simple service. It will be getting data from remote api - photo and name. So far I have a working fetch example:

```js
const div = document.getElementById('author');

const url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=1';

var f = fetch(url);

f.then(onFulfilled).then(building);

function onFulfilled(response){
 return response.json();
};

function building(data){
 var author = data.results[0];
 var img = document.createElement("img");
 img.src = author.picture.medium;
 var p = document.createElement("div");
 p.innerHTML = author.name.first + ' ' + author.name.last;
 document.getElementById('author').append(img,p);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="author"></div>
<script src="gibbon.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The question is how can I refactor this code according to Angular. I understand that fetch definitely goes to service. But what should be inside a component. And how component will get this data.

Comment: I want to know what goes to service class and what to component class and template

Comment: I understand what you want but that is not what this site is for. I recommend you read the introduction and follow the tutorial on the angular.io site, they well written. There is no sense in regurgitating how angular works here, that is not what [so] is for. See also [ask].

Comment: If you get stuck then come back and ask a specific question with all the relevant information. At that point the community will be more than happy to help.

Comment: So your answers are useless for me. I am working over the tutorial for few days already. If it was clear to me I would never had been asking this

Comment: What could be more specific to ask? I want advice on dividing my code

Comment: See [help] for links on what you can ask and how to structure your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'll help with it.

This is service

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

    @Injectable()
    export class DataFetchService {

      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
      getData() {
       return this.http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=1')
      }

    }
```

and component

```
  export class yourComponent {
      author;
      constructor(private dataFetch: DataFetchService) { }
      ngOnInit() {
        this.dataFetch.getData()
          .subscribe(res => this.author = res.results[0])   
      }

    }
```

Plus a template

```
<img src="{{author.picture.medium}}">
<p> {{author.name.first}} {{author.name.last}}</p>
```

Actually u need to import some staff therem but ide will help you, plus register service into app module. i think this question was only for a proove of concept.
Hope it will help.

Comment: I use Angular CLI so it will probably register everything automatically. This is helpful, I will try

Comment: Note that the Angular CLI does *not* automatically register a service unless you use the `-m` flag and specify the module that you want it registered in. That is most likely because services can be registered in a module OR in a component and the CLI can't assume which one you want to use.